# How to get PID of terminal inside script which is created gnome-terminal command, but keeping terminal active for later use

Tags: bash

Here is my command

`gnome-terminal --working-directory ~ -- bash -c " echo 'Execution started' && ./test && echo 'Execution finished'  ; /bin/bash"&`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "PPID ="
echo $PPID
```

I use in the end of my command `/bin/bash` to create new terminal and keep it opened for later use, but I need to store PID of terminal which is runs my script and not close it, gnome-terminal command always closed terminal which executes my `./test` script

Comment: please fix the formatting, I would edit it but I can't tel what your intent is for the code block. You can  define a block of code by enclosing it with triple-backticks (```)

Comment: Should be something like "pidof bash" and then awk

Comment: Use `pstree -p` to see the process tree with pids.

Comment: @Tigran84 : What do you mean by _opened terminal pid_? Are you looking for the PID of the _gnome-terminal_ your shell runs in?

Comment: I think I understand the problem , ```/bin/bash``` command is opened new terminal which I need to call to keep terminal opened for later use. and thatwhy PID is changed  and it is not my script ```$PPID```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, you want the PID of the terminal where you lauch a new terminal.

So:

```sh
gnome-terminal --working-directory ~ -- bash -c "FATHER_TERM_PROC=$PPID /bin/bash" &
```

In the new terminal:

```sh
$ echo PID=$$, PPID=$PPID, FATHER_TERM_PROC=$FATHER_TERM_PROC
PID=5166, PPID=5159, FATHER_TERM_PROC=4417

$ ps -o pid,ppid,args -p $$ -p $PPID $FATHER_TERM_PROC
    PID    PPID COMMAND
   4417    2043 /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal --geometry=125x40
   5159    1600 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
   5166    5159 /bin/bash
```

Now, you known, my first terminal is a XFCE terminal!

Is this what you wanted?